# Dockerized Hyperledger Caliper Exited with code 0

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

I'm using Hyperledger Caliper 0.4.2 to benchmark a Hyperldger Fabric 2.1.0 network deployed on a Docker Swarm Cluster. The Fabric network is up and running and all the Chaincodes are installed and initiated properly. The Caliper benchmark is dockerized and I'm running this on the same Docker network. However, when I start the container it hangs up after enrolling all the clients as shown in the log below.

```
    caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:21.445 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-manager]   Binding specification is present, performing binding for "fabric:2.1.0"
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:21.448 warn  [caliper] [bind]         Working directory not specified. Using "/hyperledger/caliper/workspace"
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:21.448 info  [caliper] [bind]         User-provided arguments for npm: "-g"
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:21.448 info  [caliper] [bind]         Binding for fabric@2.1.0. This might take some time...
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:21.448 info  [caliper] [bind]         Using working directory: /hyperledger/caliper/workspace
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:21.449 info  [caliper] [bind]         Calling npm with: install -g fabric-common@2.1.0 fabric-protos@2.1.0 fabric-network@2.1.0 fabric-ca-client@2.1.0
caliper_2.2    | npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
caliper_2.2    | npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
caliper_2.2    | + fabric-protos@2.1.0
caliper_2.2    | + fabric-network@2.1.0
caliper_2.2    | + fabric-common@2.1.0
caliper_2.2    | + fabric-ca-client@2.1.0
caliper_2.2    | updated 4 packages in 5.591s
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:27.588 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-manager]   Set workspace path: /hyperledger/caliper/workspace
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:27.589 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-manager]   Set benchmark configuration path: /hyperledger/caliper/workspace/scenarios/config.yaml
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:27.589 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-manager]   Set network configuration path: /hyperledger/caliper/workspace/networks/fabric/network-config3.yaml
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:27.589 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-manager]   Set SUT type: fabric
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:27.631 info  [caliper] [benchmark-validator]  No observer specified, will default to `none`
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:27.631 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]       Starting benchmark flow
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.154 info  [caliper] [fabric-connector]     Initializing gateway connector compatible with installed SDK: 2.1.0
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.586 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]       Network configuration attribute "caliper.command.start" is not present, skipping start command
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.586 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Fabric SDK version: 2.1.0; TLS: server
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.587 warn  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Administrative actions are not possible with Fabric SDK version: 2.1.0
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.587 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Fabric SDK version: 2.1.0; TLS: server
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.587 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Creating new InMemoryWallets for organizations
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.588 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Initializing administrators
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.588 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         No admin.Org1 found in caliper configuration file - unable to perform admin options
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.588 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         No admin.Org2 found in caliper configuration file - unable to perform admin options
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.588 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         No admin.Org3 found in caliper configuration file - unable to perform admin options
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.589 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         No admin.Org4 found in caliper configuration file - unable to perform admin options
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.589 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         No admin.Org5 found in caliper configuration file - unable to perform admin options
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:28.589 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Completed initializing administrators
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.946 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Initializing users
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.947 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Client client0.org1.digiblocks.com being initialized using provided crypto content
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.947 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Adding identity for name client0.org1.digiblocks.com to wallet for organization Org1
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.947 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Identity client0.org1.digiblocks.com created and imported to wallet
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.947 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Client client0.org2.digiblocks.com being initialized using provided crypto content
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.948 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Adding identity for name client0.org2.digiblocks.com to wallet for organization Org2
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.948 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Identity client0.org2.digiblocks.com created and imported to wallet
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.948 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Client client0.org3.digiblocks.com being initialized using provided crypto content
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.948 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Adding identity for name client0.org3.digiblocks.com to wallet for organization Org3
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.948 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Identity client0.org3.digiblocks.com created and imported to wallet
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.948 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Client client0.org4.digiblocks.com being initialized using provided crypto content
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.949 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Adding identity for name client0.org4.digiblocks.com to wallet for organization Org4
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.949 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Identity client0.org4.digiblocks.com created and imported to wallet
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.949 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Client client0.org5.digiblocks.com being initialized using provided crypto content
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.949 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Adding identity for name client0.org5.digiblocks.com to wallet for organization Org5
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.949 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Identity client0.org5.digiblocks.com created and imported to wallet
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.949 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Completed initializing users
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.949 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]       Executed "init" step in 1.363 seconds
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.950 warn  [caliper] [connectors/v2/fabric-gateway]         Install smart contract not available with Fabric SDK version: 2.1.0
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.950 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]       Executed "install" step in 0 seconds
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.952 info  [caliper] [monitor.js]   Attempting to create resource monitor of type docker
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.954 info  [caliper] [default-observer]     Observer interval set to 5000 seconds
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.955 info  [caliper] [round-orchestrator]   Preparing worker connections
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.956 info  [caliper] [worker-orchestrator]  Launching worker 1 of 1
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.962 info  [caliper] [worker-orchestrator]  Messenger not configured, entering configure phase...
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.962 info  [caliper] [worker-orchestrator]  No existing workers detected, entering worker launch phase...
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:29.963 info  [caliper] [worker-orchestrator]  Waiting for 1 workers to be connected...
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:30.387 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-worker]    Worker is a locally forked process, skipping binding step already performed by the manager process
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:30.389 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-worker]    Set workspace path: /hyperledger/caliper/workspace
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:30.389 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-worker]    Set benchmark configuration path: /hyperledger/caliper/workspace/scenarios/config.yaml
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:30.389 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-worker]    Set network configuration path: /hyperledger/caliper/workspace/networks/fabric/network-config3.yaml
caliper_2.2    | 2021.04.17-14:45:30.389 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-worker]    Set SUT type: fabric
caliper_2.2 exited with code 0
```

The strange this is it does not output any errors. Following is the Docker-Compose file of the Caliper

```
version: "3"
networks:
  caliper-overlay:
    external:
      name: caliper-overlay

services:
  caliper_2_2:
    container_name: caliper_2.2
    image: hyperledger/caliper:0.4.2
    command: launch manager --caliper-fabric-gateway-enabled --caliper-fabric-gateway-localhost=false
    environment:
      - CALIPER_BIND_SUT=fabric:2.1.0
      - CALIPER_BENCHCONFIG=scenarios/config.yaml
      - CALIPER_NETWORKCONFIG=networks/fabric/network-config3.yaml
    volumes:
      - ./:/hyperledger/caliper/workspace
    networks:
      caliper-overlay:
        aliases:
          - caliper.digiblocks.com
```

Any insights to debug this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: If someone having this issue I highly recommend using the CLI version of Caliper. Just make sure you use all the port accessible from the Caliper host machine in the network configuration.